# PHP - instanceof v === null

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there a specific benefit of using instanceof instead of === null before initializing objects in php.

I see code like this all the time in the Zend framework:

```
if (!self::$_httpClient instanceof Zend_Http_Client) {
        /**
         * @see Zend_Http_Client
         */
        #require_once 'Zend/Http/Client.php';
        self::$_httpClient = new Zend_Http_Client();
    }

    return self::$_httpClient;
```

But the property cannot be set externally and will therefore be null until set

Comment: I'd say: the more strict the better. Why would you use a *relax* check if you can do a bulletproof one? ;)

Comment: Arent you then coupling those classes together every time you use that check.  Granted if its in one place then thats no big deal.

Comment: Shit happens. Checking with `instanceof` is more strict and *not a big  deal* too.

Comment: This is framework supported by different people, over many years...
Imagine if your job is to create/update this single method in the application ... so that it WORKS regardless of other possible changes over the years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its correct you can do it with your solution and the "===" but then you cannot check wheather the instance is really an instance of "Zend_Http_Client" perhaps you call another class to $_httpClient then its not NULL and its not working.

In my mind its better to use the internal functions of php to check such things.

Comment: If it's a private var that cannot happen.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Its generell. You can check if its set. But in other cases you have to know wheather its really an instance of a class to work with. When you have a private var and write the variable on the constructor then its set with an instance of xy... so when you check if its an instance of "Zend_Http_Client" its false and he cannot create the class in your example. And its not a private var its a static var.

Comment: I agree with @Stony. Say what you mean. In this example the programmer doesn't want to know if it's not null; they want to know if its not an instance of Zend_Http_Client. It's best not to rely on the rest of your code performing a certain way.

Answer (score 3):

The check is a little more definitive if you absolutely want self::$_httpClient to be a Zend_Http_Client and not anything else.

Although good programming may prevent it from being anything else, if the variable were to become a String, int, or an instance of another object it would be corrected where checking for null would not.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a singleton implementation. If that's true there is no good reason for this check - checking for `null` would be fine and more logical.

Comment: Thats what i was thinking - null seems more logical, but i would imagine there must be a reason behind this style of coding given its wide spread use in Zend.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend nearly any class in ZF. Therefore you can never be sure, that the child class would not replace setHttpClient() with different implementation. Also you can't be sure that someone would not like to use his own HTTP client implementation. With this code, you check for both at once. If it's null it works. Also when it's a class that does not extend Zend_Http_Client, it will also work.